# communications between threads / processes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Began to study the Python 3, I am trying to understand the processes/threads. There is a task - in which there is a list of objects of the class, for each of which you need to create a process/thread and call the method of the class for each of them. After working off, the method returns a string - depending on which, transfer it to another process/thread.

How best to do this and where to dig right?

I watched multiprocessing pipe communications, but I have a sense that it is a wrong way. I will be pleased if you will make a short piece of code where threads communicate with each other.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems. Check [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more asking related details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a online programming course/tutorial service. Any web serarch engine will find you a lot of well documented examples on how to exchange data between processes in Python.